# How to change the parameters of configuration files for different confignodes and datanodes of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Should the `iotdb-common.properties` configuration files of the configNode and dataNode nodes in the cluster of Apache IoTDB be consistent for every node? When it is necessary to adjust general parameters of the nodes, which node's configuration files should be adjusted, or can I only adjust some of the node's files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to change general parameters of any confignodes and datanodes, you need to keep all properties to be the same for all nodes. Therefore, you only can change fields for all nodes at one time in `iotdb-common.properties` configuration files in Apache IoTDB.